# Not able to login into phpmyadmin no matter what I do

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ampps

I changed the root account on phpmyadmin to not require a password for easier access, but after I did so it locked me out and no matter what I change in the config.inc.php file or the config.sample.inc.php file and changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] =` to true but even then it won't change. I have changed my password to manually, I have changed the `$cfg[Servers']{[$1]['auth_type']` to cookie and HTTP, to force it to login. But nothing has worked. I use AMPPS.

Comment: Just use a terminal (cmd.exe in Windows) and check if you can log in to MySQL, usually: `mysql -u root`. Also make sure you reset the password correctly, try to log in the same way but using the old password: `mysql -u root -p oldpassword`. Maybe you didn't flush privileges after resetting the password and it still requires the old one.

Comment: @biesior I'm pretty new to most of this stuff, but is there a certain command to input be ```mysql -u root``` because my command prompt isn't recognizing it as something it can do,

Comment: in such case find the MySQL binary delivered with AMPPS and use full path to execute it like `c:\path\to\ampss\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p oldpass` note that I don't know the correct path in your Win so you need to find it yourself

Comment: @biesior This isn't working for me thanks anyway though.

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you find mysql binary?

Comment: @biesior Nope, I couldn't figure it out how to run what you are putting there.

Comment: You need to find it and check, otherwise you'll stack in the place. I can try to help you, but you need to cooperate ;) It's up to you.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're seeing? Does the old password work?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch The error message I'm getting says ```mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)``` but the thing is even when I change needing a password it won't do anything, but I know it's working since I can change the authorization and see it change.

Comment: `even when I change needing a password it won't do anything, but I know it's working since I can change the authorization and see it change.` Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this. Also, did you try the old password?

Comment: Oh, also, how exactly did you change the account to not require a password?

Comment: I know I'm boring, but did you manage to login via terminal `mysql` client, trying options with and without a password? That's the best and fastest way to verify credentials. Trying to do it with PhpMyAdmin adds a redundant layer of abstraction and finally, I don't know if you have a problem with the credentials themselves, or with PMA config...

Comment: Here you have several clues what to do in such cases as well, more or less it's all about the same I suggested youe earlier: https://www.ampps.com/wiki/Unable_to_connect_phpMyAdmin

Comment: @IsaacBennetch sorry bad why of wording it, But the first way I did it was through the phpmyadmin control panel through AMPPS, then I going into my config.inc.php file and manually changing the password, manually setting it to not require a password and changing the authorization type so I could type in my username and password, the strangest thing is that even though I put in the correct username that is listed in the config file and the password that is listed in the config file, nothing has worked so far

Comment: Regardless of all of the other answers that give us clues, trying through the command-line client as suggested by biesior is going to give the most information here. There are a number of problems that could have developed along the way, from mis-typing the password to changing the password on the wrong host (since MySQL/MariaDB treat user accounts with the same username and different host fields separately, it is quite common to change the password on one account that ends up not being the one used to connect). Connecting through the command-line is the best first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: Not reproducible or was caused by OP's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I got the cmd issue figured out, in the end it didn't work, a full reinstall is what fixed it

Comment: Next time when you'll want to modify the only root account, create and **test** a secondary one with full privileges before drastic changes, just to avoid the situation that you can not access your own database. BTW using root account withou password is just considered a bad practice, even on local dev host. Better just use some password manager to keep it.

Comment: And actually, your answer doesn't add any new quality to the Stackoverflow, therefore should be just a comment. As your problem was caused by a mistake, you generated yourself, most probably it will be closed and deleted soon.